# How to add '0' to between every 2 bits of a logic vector

Tags: vhdl, fpga

Assume we have a 32 bit `std_logic_vector` of data. I want to add a logic `'0'` between every 2 bits. 
Take for example; all ones `11111....1111` is going to be `101010101....1010101.`

Comment: how big should be your output, 64 bit?

Comment: @GiampietroSeu 67 bits total. The last 4 bits(63 through 66) are going to be '0', think it's not big deal but couldn't think how adding '0' between them

Comment: Your description *I wanna add logic '0' to between every 2 bits* says you want to add 31 '0's, (*between*). Is your description erroneous or is the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `'0'` in between with a function:

```vhdl
function add_zeros(std_logic_vector_in : std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
   variable std_logic_vector_out : std_logic_vector(std_logic_vector_in'length*2 -2 downto 0);
begin 
   for i in std_logic_vector_in'range loop
      std_logic_vector_out(i*2) := std_logic_vector_in(i);
      if (i /= std_logic_vector_in'length-1) then
         std_logic_vector_out(i*2+1) := '0';
      end if;
   end loop;
   return std_logic_vector_out;
end function;
```

For the final `'0'` you can add them with simple concatenation.

If you have:

```vhdl
signal initial_signal : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal final_signal   : std_logic_vector(66 downto 0);
```

Then you can just write:

```
final_signal   <= '0' & '0' & '0' & '0' & add_zeros(initial_signal);
```

Comment: I got what you've done, and I wonder that can't be done within a process with one clock? Same for loop inside the process.

Comment: @huytergan I'm not sure what you are asking, you can use the function inside a clocked process if that is your question

Comment: I got it, highly appreciated!